# Installing two versions of PHP in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php

How to install two versions of PHP in Ubuntu 14.04. Help me, please.

I need test the app of my client in PHP 5.3 because the server run in this version, but I can not uninstall the PHP 5.5 of my workstation because of my recent work

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/50344/how-to-have-two-version-of-php-installed-and-switch-easily

Comment: AFIK, easiest way is to use virtualization, such as LXC, OpenVZ, or KVM and install what you need on a test machine. Alternately, you can install from source into /usr/local , and then configure php to use that version. In the long run, maintaining an old version of PHP is not going to work.

Comment: Thansks a lot. I'll do it!!!