# unable to change php version on cli

Tags: 14.04

I have install php versions **5.6,7.0 and 7.1** . But `php -v` returns

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21 (cli) (built:feb 9 2017) <br>
copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
```

**I also tried these commands**

```
 a2enmod php7.1 
 a2dismod php5.6 
 service apache2 restart
```

but they don't work ..

so how can i run multiple versions of php on terminal?

Comment: Running multiple versions of php might get complicated. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50344/how-to-have-two-versions-of-php-installed-and-switch-easily-between-them).

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `dpkg -l | grep php`. P.S.: PHP cli has nothing to do with Apache.

Comment: How to have two versions of PHP installed and switch easily between them?  does not solve with link ...  i have try all the command and all given suggestion .......