# Unable to start apache2

Tags: server, apache2, php, php7

I use Ubuntu 18.04.

Command `sudo service apache2 restart` returns an error.

```
  kurusa kernel: apache2[17035]: segfault at 7f478cc64e00 ip 00007f4788e13fcf sp 00007ffdb66f0620 error 6 in libphp7.0.so[7f4788bc1000+390000]
  kurusa apachectl[17032]: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
  kurusa apachectl[17032]: Action 'start' failed.
```

These are some lines from `journalctl -xe` result:

```
   kurusa anacron[16951]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-12-19
   kurusa anacron[16951]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
   kurusa wpa_supplicant[1022]: TDLS: Invalid frame - payloadtype=1 category=240 action=10
   kurusa wpa_supplicant[1022]: TDLS: Invalid frame - payloadtype=1 category=240 action=10
   kurusa sudo[17006]:   kurusa : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ps -f -p 4489
   kurusa sudo[17006]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
   kurusa sudo[17006]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
   kurusa sudo[17008]:   kurusa : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ps -f -p 2197
   kurusa sudo[17008]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
   kurusa sudo[17008]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
   kurusa sudo[17011]:   kurusa : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/kill 2197
   kurusa sudo[17011]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
   kurusa sudo[17011]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
   kurusa sudo[17021]:   kurusa : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ps -f -p 4489
   kurusa sudo[17021]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
   kurusa sudo[17021]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
   kurusa sudo[17026]:   kurusa : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
   kurusa sudo[17026]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Here is my `apache2.conf`:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 5
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/kurusa/proj>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Also the command `sudo a2dismod php7.0` returned:

```
ERROR: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load is not a symbolic link, not deleting
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: A segmentation fault means a bug in an application, in this case `libphp7.0.so`. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70380. The [default `php` version for 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php) is 7.2. Could you specify why and how you installed PHP 7.0?

Comment: @Melebius so i just need to install php7.2, enable it and disable 7.0?

Comment: I think this might be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439812/apache-not-starting-in-linux-mint

Comment: @Racoon I’d definitely try to upgrade to PHP 7.2 if it’s possible.

Comment: @RoVo, `apachectl configtest` returned `Syntax OK`

Comment: @Melebius, i instaled php7.2 and `php -v` says that i have `PHP 7.2.13-1`, so i tried to run `sudo a2dismod php7.0`, but it returned error `ERROR: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load is not a symbolic link, not deleting`

Comment: @RoVo and my  libphp7.0.so is empty

Comment: Check the contents of the `mods-enabled` using the command `ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled`. PHP 7.0 might have been removed automatically while installing 7.2. Can Apache be started now?

Comment: @Melebius apache unable to start. all php modules from `mods-enabled` are `php5.6.conf, php5.6.load, php7.0.conf and php7.0.load`. But `php -v` still show that php php version is php7.2

Comment: Have you the package [`libapache2-mod-php`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libapache2-mod-php) installed correctly? I guess only one version should appear in `mods-enabled` at any time. If you want to switch versions, please check https://askubuntu.com/questions/50344/how-to-have-two-versions-of-php-installed-and-switch-easily-between-them. And please [edit] your question to reflect all the details you posted in comments. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage.